# why my python is not printing else , elif blocks statement when i run them?

Tags: python

i am a new baby in python
here is my question

```py
is_hot="true" 
if is_hot : 
     print ("it's a hot day ")
     print ("drink plenty of water ")

else : 
      print(" it's a cold day ") 
      print("wear a warm cloth")
```

when i run the program i get

```
it's a hot day 
drink plenty of water
```

but if change the boolean value to "false" i still getting the same msg again and again . pls what's the problem here ?? that i still getting only one msg it's a hot day drink plenty of water

over and over again , thought i suppose to get

```
it's a cold day 
wear a warm cloth
```

when i change the boolean value to "false"

but on my python , it's only one msg that continue to come out each time i run the program

Comment: any string of length greater than `0` will get evaluated to `True`

Answer (score 3):

You actually writing `"true"` with quotes? `True` and `False` values in python are `True` and `False` without quotes and capitalized, otherwise they're interpreted as strings.

Also, you can try numerically `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

Comment: they are not necessarily otherwise interpreted as strings, they can be seen as a name and raise `NameError`, also for numbers, any `int`eger (and most `float`s) other than `0` is considered truthy and only `0` is falsey

Comment: Best would be to link the docs - [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).